# cual es su función de mariadb-client

Tags: mariadb

en la pagina de mariadb solo hay `mariadb-server` para instalar en las versiones `10.0, 10.1, 10.2 10.3` y no hay mariadb-client la pregunta es: si es necesario instalar `mariadb-client` y cual es su función principal, alguna aclaración por favor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: es para acceder a las bases de datos por linea de comandos

Comment: El client es la CLI que ayuda accedas al server para poder manipular DB y se instala junto con el server